# cannot fetch likes from facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need your help as I think I have reached my skills limit at this point.
I'm developing a code to fetch user data from Facebook using graph API and store it into MYSQL database.
so far I've been able to retrieve and store all what I want except the likes.

here's the code:

```
function getUserData() {
        $fb_cookie = $this->getCookie();
        if($fb_cookie) {
            $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$this->getAccessToken();
            $data = json_decode($this->getDataFromUrl($url));
            $fb['id'] = $data->id;
            $fb['first_name'] = $data->first_name;
            $fb['last_name'] = $data->last_name;
            $fb['email'] = $data->email;
            $fb['likes'] = $data->likes;
            $fb['hometown'] = $data->hometown->name;
            //tokens
            $fb['token'] = $fb_cookie['access_token'];
            $fb['token_expires'] = $fb_cookie['expires'];
            return $fb;
        }
    }
```

although I have the permission "user_likes" in the token. still cannot store or retrieve the data to save it into MYSQL.

```
function update_members($criteria=array()) {
    $fb_user_id = $criteria['fb_user_id'];
        $fb_first_name = $criteria['fb_first_name'];
    $fb_last_name = $criteria['fb_last_name'];
    $fb_email = $criteria['fb_email'];
    $fb_likes = $criteria['fb_likes'];
    $fb_hometown = $criteria['fb_hometown'];

        }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$GLOBALS['db_table']['members']." 
            (fb_user_id, first_name, last_name, fb_email, fb_likes, hometown) 
            VALUES ('$fb_user_id', '$fb_first_name', '$fb_last_name', '$fb_email', '$fb_likes', '$fb_hometown')";
            $u1 = new MySqlTable();
            $u1->executeQuery($sql);
```

so far I've been able to store all the data but the likes.
thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/me` call does't contain likes.

You'll havta call `/me/likes` which returns something like this:

```
  { "data": [
      {
         "name": "Hunger Games",
         "category": "Book",
         "id": "114531238562971",
         "created_time": "2012-11-28T03:55:27+0000"
      },
      {
         "name": "CivicRush",
         "category": "Software",
         "id": "160319707426901",
         "created_time": "2012-11-27T01:53:40+0000"
      },
      ...
      ]
  }
```

Keep in mind that a single column in a table will not hold all the likes, unless you want to comma delimit them or store them in json. You'll need another table called `member_likes` with `user_id`,`page_id`,`name`, etc. and each page they like is a row in that table

Comment: Thanks for the hint Tommy. should I make another function just for the likes? or can I modify the current function without messing with the other data fields?

Comment: I can't know for sure because idk your application design, but it looks like `getUserData`is part of a class that is handling the access tokens. So probably within that function. In which case $fb['likes'] is going to be an array